# How to get support of TypeScript with Sublime Text 3?

Tags: angular, typescript, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I am currently working in Angular and I get good support of Typescript with Sublime Text.

How can I get support of TypeScript with my Sublime Text editor?

I tried to hit <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and then typed **TypeScript** but I did not get any TypeScript results.

I have gone through the [official TypeScript website](https://www.typescriptlang.org/#download-links) and I have cloned the Sublime Text to my PC.

I have installed TypeScript on my laptop - what can I do next?

Comment: AngularJS or Angular? You might have chosen the wrong tag.

Answer (score 180):

You can do this by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> write `ipc` and press enter to open the Package Manager. After that, type ***`TypeScript`*** and choose the first option which is published by http://typescriptlang.org.

Note: For Mac OS users, use <kbd>Command (⌘)</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>.

Comment: After doing this, open a type script file in Sublime, in the right bottom of the sublime you can see plain text. Click  on that plain text. A vertical pop up box (side nav bar) will be displayed. Scroll down to select "Typescript". After selecting you can see the color changes in that file.

Comment: after installing "install packages" type "ctrl+shift+p" then type "install packages" and then when it will give a list of packages to choose, type "TypeScript" and press enter.

Comment: Just making sure the case is perfect, otherwise they won't show up. Waiting is important too.

Comment: If you want to see the loading process of the plugin(typescript), select "View" menu, and click "Show console", and you may "Hide console" when you don`t want to see it anymore.

Comment: If "Goto Definition" does not work, you may need to reinstall the TypeScript plugin.

Answer (score 50):

If it's not already done, you first have to install the **Package installer**, like that:

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>
- Type "inst" and select `Install Package Control`

The following pop-up appears:

> Package Control was successfully installed
>
> Use Command Palette and type "Install Package" to get started

Now you can install the **Typescript** support like that:

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>
- Type "inst" and select `Package Control: Install Package`
- Type "type" and select "Typescript"

Now you can open a `file.ts`and change the type to **Typescript** clicking in the right bottom of the editor where **Plain Text** is selected by default.

Comment: I had to CMD+Q and restart Sublime for mouse hover and checking to work

Answer (score 22):

If you are using mac OS
then use the following command

```
cd ~/"Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages"
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Sublime-Plugin.git TypeScript
```

After that press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> in sublime text 3
, then type "TypeScript" and select "TypeScript" and press enter.

And on Windows:

```
cd "%APPDATA%\Sublime Text 3\Packages"
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Sublime-Plugin.git TypeScript
```

After that press Ctrl+shift+p write install packages and press enter, then type "TypeScript" and select "TypeScript" and press enter.

Comment: Searched a lot for this solution, thanks! Works with Sublime Text 2 too, just do `cd ~/"Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages"` instead.

Answer (score 16):

(If you're on Mac, press **Cmd** instead of **Ctrl** in the key combos below.)

Press **Ctrl+Shift+P** and type "Install package". If "Install package control" appears as an option, pick it, and then press **Ctrl+Shift+P** again and type "Install package". Pick "Package Control: Install Package". Wait a moment and a new dropdown menu will appear. Type "TypeScript" and pick the option with that exact name.

Comment: Thank you this one was easy you should be on top

Answer (score 13):

There is a [TypeScript plugin](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/TypeScript) for Sublime written by Microsoft that you can install. I would recommend installing it via [PackageControl](https://packagecontrol.io/installation#st3) to make sure that it stays up to date.

The plugin provides syntax highlighting and a build system for building TypeScript applications using node.js and the TypeScript compiler (which is presumably what you mentioned downloading above).

The page linked includes install instructions as well as information on what it does for you and how to use it.

Answer (score 5):

There is a more newer package available than [Microsoft](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-Sublime-Plugin). Use this official  [LSP-typescript](https://github.com/sublimelsp/LSP-typescript) plugin.

Comment: Yes -- and also see this issue on the package from Microsoft: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-Sublime-Plugin/issues/786 -- "This package hasn't been properly maintained for a long time [...] Due to providing generally a poor experience for the users, the ST community has decided to restrict availability of this package to ST3" with a recommendation to use LSP

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu

```
cd /home/userNameOftheMachine/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages

git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Sublime-Plugin.git TypeScript
```

Then View > Syntex > Typescript

Comment: Thanks to @turingtested for the suggestion to clone into the Packages directory instead of the base sublime-text-3 directory. The same applies to this answer which worked for me.

Comment: The correct directory is `cd ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages`. Then it works.

Answer (score 0):

Press : CTRL + SHIFT + P
then type "install package"
then type "typescript"
click to install and Restart your Sublime Text editor. 
See your codes...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11PL0.png)